# Is there a way to display recent work item activity?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Jira has a feature called Activity Streams, which allows for a gadget to be displayed on dashboards to show what recent changes have been made to issues within a particular stream. This could show link changes, attachments added, fields updated, etc. Is there any way to do something like this with a TFS dashboard widget? 
I've done some searching, but haven't come across anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Activity Feed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davesmits.VSTSActivityFeed) extension.

With the activity feed, you can see what's happening in your team project within a glance. You can use it on your dashboard by putting a widget on it, or simply open the hub. The Activity Feed gives a summary of all recent changes of work items, commits, pull requests and builds. It tells who changed a task, who logged a bug and who made committed code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I happened to come across this just after my post. Only problem is that it doesn't work very well. The widget seems to be ok, but the Activity Hub doesn't load any data, and the "see more updates" link from the widget doesn't set the filters on the Activity hub to match those of the widget. If that page would work, I would push this out to my users.

Comment: Which TFS version do you use? you can email the bug to: dave@familie-smits.com

Comment: TFS2017.2. I did email Dave, but have not heard anything back yet.